# What could be the algorithm for ordered 9 digit problem?

Tags: algorithm, math, digits

Given any 3 digits N as an input,

we can only use digits from 1 to 9, in such a way that order never breaks and any repetition of number.

for example

```
If N = 150. 
123 + 4 + 5 - 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 150
```

We can combine digits and insert `'-'` and `'+'` operations to get the desired N value.

Comment: This question does not belong here, as it is not about programming. Try on [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Do we have to consume all 9 digits while getting the sum? Also, the first that comes to my mind is backtracking.

Comment: Say 150 can be made from 148 + 2 as well.

Comment: @vivek_23  
Yes, we have to consume all 9 digits and they have to be in ascending order.

Comment: @AnnQuraishi What do you mean by ascending order?

Answer (score 3):

Line up the numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.
There are 8 spaces between these numbers. Each space could be a '+' or a '-' or a blank (joining the digits together).
Thus, there are 3 ** 8 i.e., 6561 different possible combinations of operations you could use.
That's small enough to just try all of them in a loop and check which one works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this(this code is written by python):

```
N = 150
digit_from, digit_to = 1, 9    ### from 1 to 9 ###

def find(N, pos, equation, num, coff):

    if pos > digit_to:
        if N - coff * num == 0:
            print(equation)
    else:
        find( N-coff*num, pos+1, equation+'+'+str(pos), pos, 1 )   ### plus  ###
        find( N-coff*num, pos+1, equation+'-'+str(pos), pos, -1 )  ### minus ###
        find( N, pos+1, equation+str(pos), num*10+pos, coff )      ### blank ###
    return

find( N, digit_from + 1, '150 = 1', digit_from, 1 )
```

Result(In case of N = 150 and digits between 1 to 9):

```
150 = 1+23+45-6+78+9
150 = 1+234+5+6-7-89
150 = 1-2+3-4+56+7+89
150 = 12+3+45-6+7+89
150 = 123+4+5-6+7+8+9
150 = 123+45+6-7-8-9
150 = 123-4-56+78+9
```

Thanks